# Example of State monad in business application

Tags: scala, functional-programming, state, monads

I am looking for a simple example of State monad in a business application.

I have found good examples -- [memoisation](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/memoisation-with-state-using-scala/) to calculate Fibonacci numbers and random numbers [generation](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) -- but I would like to see an example from a business domain (preferably in Scala).

For example, I can easily find examples of using Option, Either, List, Reader, and Writer monads:

- *option* :  look up an entity (order, product, customer, whatever) which does not exist
- *either* : any failure
- *list*   : customer orders, order items, etc.
- *reader* :  read any entity from the database
- *writer* :  write to the log

Now I am looking for something similar for State monad, i.e. any stateful computation with a mutable state, as I understand it.

Comment: What kind of business application do you have in mind? Random number generation is used in business quite a lot, you know.

Comment: I mean orders processing software, for example, supply chain software, billing, CRM, etc.

Comment: Can you think of an application that keeps track of some state? Then you have an application where `State` might be appropriate.

Comment: Most applications I am thinking of are client/server and they are stateless. The state is either stored in the database or in the client. That's why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

The typical application where I reach for `State` is where I need a *supply* of values, like a random number generator or a supply of unique identifiers.

Another typical use case is testing an application that interacts with a database. Using `State`, you can simulate an in-memory database and check that the program manipulates the database in the expected way.

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking about processing a single order. Suppose I am writing a function to calculate the payment for a given order. The function calculates discounts, VAT, converts the currency, and finally returns the payment total. The order looks like a `State` here. Does it make sense ?

Comment: I am not sure that makes sense to me. How does the order change?

Comment: On the second thought it did not make sense to me either. I am thinking about other example.